# Rebase branch using a Tag as upstream

Tags: libgit2sharp

I am trying to use LibGit2Sharp to rebase a feature branch using a Tag as upstream.
The initial graph looks like this:

```
          * -- * -- * (featureA)
         /          
        /
 *--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*-- (master)
       |        |        |        |    
       tag1    tag2     tag3    tag4
```

The idea is to rebase **featureA** branch on **master**, but not on the HEAD of master (last commit), but rather on the commit corresponding to **tag2**.

The end result would be something like this:

```
                   * -- * -- * (featureA)
                  /          
                 /
 *--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*-- (master)
       |        |        |        |    
       tag1    tag2     tag3    tag4
```

The git syntax for this would be (and it works perfectly):

```
git rebase ref/tags/tag2 featureA
```

However, LibGit2Sharp syntax only allows passing in a Branch as argument for the *upstream* param.

```
var rebaseOptions = new RebaseOptions {...};
var identity = new Identity(...);

Branch branch = repo.Head;
Tag upstreamTag = repo.Tags[ontoTag]; 

var rebaseResult = repo.Rebase.Start(
    branch, 
    upstream, // <-- this is where I am struggling to pass in this Tag as upstream
    null, 
    identity, 
    rebaseOptions);
```

Any idea on how I can achieve this result via LibGit2Sharp?